# Is it normal for mouse movement tracking to add on the page when I use the Register() function from the Swiper web component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

why, when I use Register() from the Swiper web component on my page, mouse movement tracking is superimposed on the page, is this normal? I dont add this addEventListener

i trying understand what this addEventListener doing in my code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.